# Maven site Google issue in China

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

on and all pages generated with newer template e.g. http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

There is code

```
  <input value="https://maven.apache.org" name="sitesearch" type="hidden"/>
  <input class="search-query" name="q" id="query" type="text" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=search-form"></script>

          <hr />

           <div id="poweredBy">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

that is between left panel and main text.

In China google.com is not available and browser is waiting for response from google.com for 2 minutes and does not get it.

All this time the page is not displayed.

The solution is to put those script loading into end of page after main content.

[image: maven-google-problem]

Now, where exactly should be modified or changed in Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [Maven Page](http://maven.apache.org/) you can find the [Skins](http://maven.apache.org/skins/) which contains the definition of the style and look of the site...
At the moment the whole site is using [Maven Fludio Skin version 1.4](http://maven.apache.org/skins/maven-fluido-skin/)

If you have issues please fill in a [JIRA ticket](http://maven.apache.org/skins/maven-fluido-skin/issue-tracking.html). After this has been change in Fluido skin (and release the Fluido skin) the whole Maven site must be released new....

Comment: Issue tracker is at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSKINS/component/12326474